# How to show open, close, high and low in tooltip when the chart type is 'line' in highstocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I want to show the value of open, close, high and low for a symbol but it seems highstock only  displays that value when chart type is ohlc or candlestick but not in line. My workaround for this problem is producing two chart with same data, line(making it visible) and ohlc(making it invisible) and extracting open, close, high and low from second type and displaying it in tooltip. I'm sure this is not a right way. Does anyone has any solution.

My tooltip formatter

```
  formatter: function() {


                var s=' ';
                $.each(this.points, function(i, series) {

                   //when the series is of type 'line', series.point.open is undefined but works great on 'ohlc' type
 n=new Date(series.point.x);

 s += 'Open: <span style="font-weight:bold">' +series.point.open + '</span> Close: <span style="font-weight:bold">' +series.point.close + '</span> High: <span style="font-weight:bold">'+ series.point.high + '</span> Low: <span style="font-weight:bold">' + series.point.low + '</span>';

                });
                return s;

            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7G9Cj/4/

Comment: You can store each candle inside an array indexed by the date in utc, then store the array with the serie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. Here is the solution in case someone needs it.

```
formatter: function() {
  var s = ' ';

  $.each(this.points, function(i, series) {
      for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        if (ohlc[i][0] == series.point.x) //ohlc holds my main data
        {
          s += 'Open: <span style="font-weight:bold">' + ohlc[i][1] 
            + '</span> Close: <span style="font-weight:bold">' + ohlc[i][4] 
            + '</span> High: <span style="font-weight:bold">' + ohlc[i][2] 
            + '</span> Low: <span style="font-weight:bold">' + ohlc[i][3] 
            + '</span>';
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return s;
}
```